# Asymptotics for Christoffel number 

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

What is the order for the following sum $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\lambda _i}{1-x _ i}$ where $\lambda _i$-i-th Christoffel number and $x _i$- i-th zero of n-th Legendre polynomial.

P.S
Christoffel number $\lambda_ k =\int\limits_ {-1}^{1}(\frac{p_ n(x)}{p'_ n(x)(x-x_k)})^2 dx$. The problem came from the following one: we want to find maximum value of $\frac{(\int g(x)dx)^2}{\int (1-x)g^2(x)dx}$ over the set of nonnegative on $[-1,1]$ polynomials of degree $n$(not exact value but the order, after using cradrature formula the problem reduced to this one).

Comment: Perhaps you should give some background or explanation of why you care about this. It's likely that this will be closed as "too localized" as it stands.

Also -- your spelling of Chri/ystoffel is inconsistent.

Comment: Could you at least add a reference to a definition of Christoffel numbers? (Legendre polynomials I know; they are described here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomial .)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following reference, it may be useful:

AMS Memoirs #535 : Christoffel functions and orthogonal polynomials for exponential weights on [-1,1]
 By Levin and Lubinsky

Comment: I've already proved that it is something like $\log n$, but thanks for useful reference.